# How do I get my NPM module to install its dependencies correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, module

I'm having problems with my home-rolled NPM module as when installed it installs most of it's dependencies in the applications node_modules directory, instead of containing it inside the module itself.

Ex;

```
APP
    node_modules
        MY_MODULE
            node_modules
                <ALL deps from MY_MODULE should be installed here>
        <SOME/MOST deps from MY_MODULE are installed here>
```

The above causes issues because I have dependencies that require a specific version that's installed under MY_MODULE/node_modules and NOT under MY_APP/node_modules.

For instance; I have Webpack 3 installed under APP/node_modules but MY_MODULE requires Webpack 4 and that is installed under MY_MODULE/node_modules as you would expect.
But everything else, that requires Webpack 4, is installed under APP/node_modules and thus gives an error message.

So, in the app I have a package.json:
devDependencies: "webpack": "^3.12.0",

And in my NPM module I have a package.json:
"dependecies": [
"webpack": "^4.12.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
]

webpack-cli is installed under APP/node_modules and thus complains that it requires Webpack 4 and that it couldn't be found.

if webpack-cli instead installed itself under APP / node_modules / MY_MODULE / node_modules it would work.

How can I get it to do that?

Thanks,

/J

Answer (score 1):

`<ALL deps from MY_MODULE should be installed here>`

They shouldn't. This was true for NPM v2. This behaviour had been changed in NPM v3, and now it's v6.

In case dependencies have dependencies with different version constraints that can be satisfied with single `webpack` (which is one of the reasons why `node_modules` was flattened in NPM v3), there will be:

```
node_modules/webpack
```

Otherwise there will be multiple dependencies that will be used by packages that depend on them:

```
node_modules/webpack@3.12.0
node_modules/webpack@4.12.0
```

Comment: Yes, I read something about that. But how can that work in this case? The deps are mostly installed in the "general" node_modules (the top one) but some of them require a version that's only installed under MY_MODULE/node_modules and therefor can't find it, saying that: webpack-cli@3.0.8 requires a peer of webpack@^4.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself

Comment: I've checked, webpack is peer dependency of webpack-cli so webpack is not its dependency. `webpack-cli@3.0.8 requires a peer of webpack@^4.x.x but none is installed` is a *warning*, not an *error*. It can be ignored if it works for you, though I would expect that `"dependecies": [ "webpack": "^4.12.0", ...` would install it. I'm not sure why a module would have webpack and webpack-cli as *dependencies* and not *devDependencies*. Possibly a mistake that should be ignored or fixed.